# Fetching latest file URL in Drive and posting it to Google Spreadsheet based on a criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wondering whether it's possible or not to retrieve the URL of the latest file in a Drive Folder then have it posted into a cell in Column B of a Spreadsheet.

Then there's the other part where the URL should only be posted if Column A has the word "YES". So if A has "NO" URL isn't necessary.

The full scenario would be like this.

1. Picture uploaded into Drive Folder.
2. "YES" is entered into A1.
3. URL of latest uploaded picture is fetched then pasted into B1.
4. Then it continues for all the other rows as well.

Theoretically, that's how I want it to work. But I don't know whether it could work or not.

This is the script that I use to upload picture into Drive:

```
    function doGet(e) {
return message("Error: no parameters in doGet");

}

function doPost(e) {
 if (!e.parameters.filename || !e.parameters.file || !e.parameters.imageformat) {
   return message("Error: Bad parameters in doPost");
 } else {
   var imgf = e.parameters.imageformat[0].toUpperCase();
   var mime =
       (imgf == 'BMP')  ? MimeType.BMP
     : (imgf == 'GIF')  ? MimeType.GIF
     : (imgf == 'JPEG') ? MimeType.JPEG
     : (imgf == 'JPG')  ? MimeType.JPEG
     : (imgf == 'PNG')  ? MimeType.PNG
     : (imgf == 'SVG')  ? MimeType.SVG
     : false;
   if (mime) {
     var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.file, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
     var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, mime, e.parameters.filename);
     DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder Id').createFile(blob);
     return message("Success");
   } else {
     return message("Error: Bad image format");
   }
 }
}

function message(msg) {
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({Result: msg })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

While this is the script I use to enter "YES" or "NO" into Column A:

```
    function doGet(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Sheet_URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");

    addRecord(e,sheet);

    }

    function doPost(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Sheet_URL");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");

    addRecord(e,sheet);

    }

    function addRecord(e,sheet) {
    var HvPict = e.parameter.HvPict;

sheet.appendRow([Hv.Pict]);

}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `1. Picture uploaded into Drive Folder.`, how will you upload the file? Manual or script? 2. About `2. "YES" is entered into A1.`, when the file is uploaded, how will you put `YES` to the cell?

Comment: 1. Uploading from an app through a script (which is already okay), 2. "YES" will be entered from an app through a script as well (which is also okay).

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. In that case, how about retrieving the URL and putting it to the cell "B1", when the script is run and put `YES` to the cell "A1"? I think that this flow can be run continuously using the uploading process as the trigger. By the way, I could understand that the script of `I use to upload picture into Drive` is used when the file is uploaded using Web Apps. But about the script of `I use to enter "YES" or "NO" into Column A`, how do you run the script? And can I ask you about the logic for putting the value of `NO` to Spreadsheet?

Comment: Ah, yes. Maybe it was too vague from how I explained it the first time. Actually, I am trying to make an Name Registration app that sends data to Spreadsheet. So it would actually be like in `col A = Name` , `col B=Have picture or not` , and `col c=if has picture then link to the picture`. Therefore "YES" here would mean the person has a picture, and it should be the most recently uploaded, so a link should be placed in C, but the person didn't have picture, B would have "NO" then the link to the most recent uploaded picture into the folder is not necessary.

Comment: The script of entering "YES" or "NO" is run when I send over data from the app that I have. Sort of like a form app of some kind.

Comment: Hi there @HMProduction! I don't understand the third and fourth points of the full scenario. If the URL of the latest uploaded picture is fetched and pasted into the B column, wouldn't every row have the same picture? Please, clarificate this to me so I can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about the logic for putting `YES` and `NO`. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron The picture folder will constantly be updated every time a a row is filled. Like I mentioned, I'm using this to record names and people's pictures. They will upload a picture first, then enter their name into the spreadsheet. Once their name is entered, then the script will fetch the most recent upload in the folder, grab the URL, then paste the URL in the same row as their name.

Comment: @Tanaike It will be "YES" if that person has uploaded a picture beforehand, and it will be "NO" if there were no picture uploaded before their name was entered.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How do you confirm about `It will be "YES" if that person has uploaded a picture beforehand`?

Comment: @Tanaike They will enter "YES" into the column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `It will be "YES" if that person has uploaded a picture beforehand`, I asked about the method for confirming whether "that person has uploaded a picture beforehand".

Comment: Yeah, because it will go through a form in an app before entered into the sheet. So if they have uploaded, they will just put in YES into the column.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how do you confirm about `NO`? I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike The same way YES is entered. If they didn't upload a picture beforehand, they will simply pick "NO".

Comment: Thank you for replying. How do you confirm about `If they didn't upload a picture beforehand`?

Comment: @Tanaike Through an app. The second script in my question have that parameter to be filled in. They will just choose YES / NO. YES if they uploaded a picture, NO if they did not upload a picture.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, in your situation, there are 2 HTML forms. The file is uploaded at 1st one. The value of `YES` or `NO` is put at the 2nd one. And you want to put the URL to Spreadsheet when the 2nd one is run. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, how do you search the file at the script of 2nd one? And by the way, can you update your question by including the detail information?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, it's close to that. And that was my original question, how to search for the file from the drive, that's what I wanted to ask. Because from my perspective, the easiest method would be to have a script that retrieve the URL of the most recent upload in a Google Drive Folder, then put it into the spreadsheet. But I don't know how I can do that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the uploaded files are put to the specific folder and the uploaded files are not modified, the latest uploaded file can be retrieved by checking the created time of the file. But in this case, I think that when the several users are uploaded, the user's information is required to be included in the filename and the property of the file. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike That wouldn't be necessary I think. Just checking the created time should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand about your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to retrieve the URL of the latest uploaded file in the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In your case, I thought that the method of `getDateCreated()` in Class File might be able to be used. So how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function getLatestFile(folderId) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({url: file.getUrl(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].url;
}

function myFunction() {
  var folderId = "###";
  var lastFileUrl = getLatestFile(folderId);
  Logger.log(lastFileUrl)
}
```

- When you run the script, please set `folderId`. This script retrieves the files in the folder of `folderId`.
- When you run the function of `myFunction()`, the URL of the latest created file is retrieved.

#### Note:

- In your case, above function might should be used at the script of the 2nd HTML form.
- If in your actual situation, the uploaded file is modified and you want to retrieve the latest modified file, please try to use `getLastUpdated()` instead of `getDateCreated()`.
- In this case, `fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});` might not be required.

#### References:

- [getDateCreated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdatecreated)
- [getLastUpdated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getlastupdated)

### Added:

```
function getLatestFile(folderId) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  var fileObj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileObj.push({url: file.getUrl(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  fileObj.sort(function(a, b) {return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)});
  return fileObj[0].url;
}

function doGet(e) { // or doPost(e)
  var folderId = "###";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Sheet_URL");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");
  sheet.appendRow([e.parameter.HvPict, getLatestFile(folderId)]);
}
```

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thanks for this, but a quick question, does this script work up to just retrieve the URL but not posting to spreadsheet?

Comment: @HM Production Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my incomplete answer. In above script, a function returns the URL of the latest uploaded file. You can use this function by adding it to the script of your 2nd HTML form. So I added one more sample script for your 2nd HTML form. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for not being able to immediately reply to your answer as I was away. I will try the script that you have prepared together with mine first and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: I've tested the script that you had prepared, and fetching the link is already working well. The link can already be fetched into the logs but now, I'm only facing problem with posting URL into spreadsheet. It gives me the parameter error when I use the second script you prepared.

Comment: @HM Production Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from `It gives me the parameter error when I use the second script you prepared.`, I cannot understand about your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the script and the detail flow for completely replicating your issue of `the parameter error`? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: It simply gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined.`

Comment: @HM Production Thank you for replying. If you directly run the function of `doGet(e)` at the script editor, such error occurs. Because `e` of `doGet(e)` is the event object of Web Apps. In your script, you are using Web Apps. So I modified the script using your script. If you want to directly run `doGet(e)` at the script editor, please modify to `sheet.appendRow([getLatestFile(folderId)]);`. If the issue was not resolved, please provide the script and the detail flow for completely replicating your issue. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.